# FileVault alternative for Ubuntu wrt key recovery

Tags: encryption, data-recovery

I acknowledge a similar question has been asked before but only with respect to encryption.  I have done whole drive encryption when I installed so that isn't a problem.
FileVault for OSX encrypts the key using a secondary public key, so that someone with the secondary private key can recover it, ie for a corporate laptop if the user gets creamed by a bus and they need access.
Is there a way to setup Ubuntu with encryption (either whole drive or just home) to similarly be recoverable via secondary key?

Backstory: my company was recently acquired and the new owners have more stringent requirements.  They do not support Linux, but will allow me to keep my existing workstation if I can meet certain requirements. This is the only one I can't figure out, encrypt the hard drive so it can be recovered if I get creamed by the previously mentioned bus (or, more likely, if I leave the company in otherwise good health). I am provided a FileVaultMaster.keychain file for this purpose.  Recovery must be as simple as possible. I'm picturing encrypting my passphrase into a file in the boot partition using the provided public key (how?), and then doing something to grub (but what?) so it can accept the master password, decrypt, and display the file.  That way it's just a menu option at boot; but if there's a more automatic way then I'm happy to hear it, too.

Comment: The way FDE works in Ubuntu is that a key is generated, and then the password you use, is used to encrypt the key. So the password already is the secondary key. I'm not sure what the keychain file you mentioned is, how exactly FileVault works in these cases, or what your company's specific requirements are, though.

Comment: The keychain file is a certificate with a public encryption key.  It's used to encrypt the passphrase which the user provides on the hard drive so that someone with the private decryption key can recover it.  It doesn't matter what happens under the covers to actually do the encryption/decryption, the important part is that I have my passphrase and they need to be able to recover it with the master password should something happen to me.

Comment: Well, since you'd need the private key to decrypt, I don't think you could just make a boot option to go through the process. Should probably be encrypted and stored on a USB stick in a secure lock box under IT's control or something to that nature. I'd say you should probably work through how the process works for your IT dept. under OSX, and then do something as close as possible to the same thing for your Ubuntu system.

Comment: I think I haven't explained very well, so I'll try again, from the beginning.  I encrypt the hard drive with my own passphrase.  On OSX I supply the keychain file which encrypts my passphrase somewhere, presumably in the boot partition, I don't know all the details.  If tomorrow I slip into a coma, my manager can boot up my Mac with a key combination, enter the private key associated with the keychain, and retrieve my passphrase.  They need something similar, with the exact same private key, for linux.  At no point do I need to know the private key.

Comment: “I encrypt the hard drive with my own passphrase” No, you don't. The LVM is encrypted with a random key (if you do it manually, you can actually see it printed in the terminal so you can back it up) and then your chosen passphrase is used to encrypt/decrypt the real key. This way you can change the passphrase without re-encrypting the whole disk (which is a costly operation).

Comment: "It doesn't matter what happens under the covers".  I said that, it does not matter what the underlying details are.  Yes, I don't literally "encrypt the hard drive with my own passphrase" but ultimately that's what is happening, the hard drive is encrypted and it requires my passphrase to decrypt it: there is no functional difference to the user.  Is there, or is there not, some way to encrypt my passphrase using the provided keychain file, then have a grub option to accept a password to decrypt and display the passphrase?